# how to synchronize a value between two entities

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.7

My project is a php project built with symfony 2.7

I have two entities: Lead and Customer.
Some user action create a Lead entity, and an admin can create a Customer entity based on a Lead.
Both the Lead and the Customer entity have a one to many relation to an entity Status (a Lead/Customer can have a status)

Up until now the Status of a Lead was independent from that of the Customer created from it (and vice versa), but now, I need to keep them synchronized.
They have to be the same.

I don't want to do that in controllers, because the status can be changed in many ways, and it's likely new ways will be added.
So I tried to do it with doctrine PreUpdate event listeners, but for some reason that's just not working (changing the other entity in the first one's PreUpdate event triggers a PreUpdate on the second one - and that probably kills it. but I'm not sure).

I'm going to keep trying fixing the PreUpdate event listeners, unless someone here has a better idea?

Thanks :-)

#### Customer PreUpdate listener

```
use CRM\CoreBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class CustomerPreUpdateListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if (!($entity instanceof Customer)) {
            return;
        }

        if($this->isStatusChanged($args)) {
            $this->syncParentLeadStatus($args);
        }
    }

    private function isStatusChanged(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        return $args->hasChangedField('status');
    }

    private function syncParentLeadStatus(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var Customer $entity */
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if(!$entity->getLead()) {
            return;
        }

        $newStatus = $args->getNewValue('status');
        $entity->getLead()->setStatus($newStatus);
        $args->getEntityManager()->persist($entity->getLead());
    }
}
```

#### Lead PreUpdate listener

```
use CRM\BasicLeadsBundle\Entity\Lead;
use CRM\CoreBundle\Entity\Customer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class LeadPreUpdateListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if (!($entity instanceof Lead)) {
            return;
        }

        if($this->isStatusChanged($args)) {
            $this->syncCustomerStatus($args);
        }
    }

    private function isStatusChanged(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        return $args->hasChangedField('status');
    }

    private function syncCustomerStatus(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        /** @var Lead $entity */
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if(0 === $entity->getCustomersCreated()->count()) {
            return;
        }

        $newStatus = $args->getNewValue('status');
        foreach ($entity->getCustomersCreated() as $customer) {
            /** @var Customer $customer */
            $customer->setStatus($newStatus);
            $args->getEntityManager()->persist($customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about adding a new property to both your entites: `skipListener` which is not a doctrine managed field. Once you run into one of your listeners set it to true in both entites and use it as another part of your `isStatusChanged` method? That way you should be able to prevent the second listener to do anything which leads to the first listener running again.

Comment: @Joe nice idea! but how will I reset that field? postUpdate event?

Comment: There should be no reason to reset it if it's not a persisted field in the database (No ORM Annotations). Within the next request cycle it will be back to default. But if you need it for some reason you should be able to just reset it in `isStatusChanged` when it's set to true, just reset to false and return false. That should not trigger the Listeners since the property is not managed by doctrine.

Comment: duh.. I guess I wrote that question at a time with too much blood in my coffee stream... thanks!

Comment: still not working, I suspect I'm having hydration problems with doctrine